# lapply on list of dataframes not working the same as FUN applied to dfs individually

Tags: r

**example data**

```
metro_2005_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
metro_2006_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6)
```

I have 20 dataframes, each named in the following format where x is a number 1-9:

metro_20XX_X

I am trying to extract the middle section into a new column, and wrote a function that works when applied on each dataframe individually called addYear.

```
addYear <- function(metro){
   metro_name <- deparse(substitute(metro))
   metro <- metro %>% mutate(Year = substr(metro_name,7,10))
   return(metro)
   }

example <- addYear(metro_2005_1)

str(example)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ col1: int  1 2 3 4 5
  $ col2: int  6 7 8 9 10
  $ Year: chr  "2005" "2005" "2005" "2005"
```

I added all 20 of my dataframes into a list called metro_append_year, and tried to apply my addYear function to all 20 of the dataframes using lapply. However, when I inspect "result" the year column is created in each of my dataframes but empty.

```
metro_append_year <- list(metro_2005_1, metro_2006_1)

result <- lapply(metro_append_year,addYear)

str(result[[1]])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col1: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ col2: int  6 7 8 9 10
 $ Year: chr  "" "" "" ""
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [reproducible example in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Moreover, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers.

Comment: You are checking one individual data frame (not all). Try `lapply(result, str)` and tell us if *Year* situation occurs across all dfs.

Comment: I edited the post to include a reproducible example, borrowing from akrun's answer for the example data.

Comment: I checked and the year is missing across all dfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could pass the 'data' and the name of the `list` element as two arguments.  Now, it becomes easier

```
addYear <- function(data, name){

   data %>% 
          mutate(Year = substr(name,7,10))

 }
lapply(names(metro_append_year), function(nm) addYear(metro_append_year[[nm]], nm))
```

#### data

```
metro_2005_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
metro_2006_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6)
metro_append_year <- mget(ls(pattern = '^metro_\\d{4}'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I am still researching as to why. So far it looks like I needed to use lapply in the function(nm) format in order to reference the names of the list elements.

From [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html):

_three basic ways to use lapply():

lapply(xs, function(x) {})
lapply(seq_along(xs), function(i) {})
lapply(names(xs), function(nm) {})
Typically you’d use the first form because lapply() takes care of saving the output for you. However, if you need to know position or name of the element you’re working with, you should use the 2nd or 3rd form_

Comment: @AlexTalbott  There are issues in getting the individual object. In your post, the single argument evaluate the object as well as extracts the substring.  Here, it is in a `list` of data.frames.  So, indexing the list to extract the object is the easiest way instead of doing some complicated steps

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a R newbie, consider a base R solution which can extract a list of objects with `mget` and iterate elementwise with `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) through list names and corresponding values. Possibly the passing of names for unquoted column aliases is the issue with your `dplyr` call.

The `within` or `transform` functions mirrors `dplyr::mutate` where you can assign column(s) in place to return the object:

```
# ALL METRO DATA FRAMES
metro_dfs <- mget(ls(pattern="metro"))

metro_dfs <- Map(function(name, df) within(df, Year <- substr(name,7,10))),
                 names(metro_dfs), metro_dfs)
```

Alternatively:

```
metro_dfs <- mapply(function(name, df) transform(df, Year = substr(name,7,10))),
                    names(metro_dfs), metro_dfs, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```